# Databse Backup output is gibberish when opening in a text editor

Tags: database, backup

Whenever I try and make a database backup and then try to view it in a text editor (notepad++) the data comes out as completely unreadable. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Database Gibberish]

I've tried different encoding, and different language selections, but nothing works. Is the database corrupted?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System → Tools → Backups option allows you to create backups of the Magento database. Backup files are compressed using the .gz format and are stored in the var/backups directory in your Magento file system.

It's likely you're trying to open the file without first uncompressing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Douglas, I was uncompressing the file before attempting to open it, and was getting just a .sql file, but I figured what the hell, might as well see if there is another layer of compression. Lo and behold, there was, and now it is no longer gibberish!